# Why does FragmentTransaction on FragmentContainerView in RecyclerView listitem only affect first element of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Inflating a layout XML file with a `FragmentContainerView` in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method of a **RecyclerView adapter** and trying to put different **Fragments** into the **FragmentContainerViews** of each list item only affects the **FragmentContainerView** in the first list item.

When creating a **listitem_layout.xml** with a `FragmentContainerView` inside a `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D47F00">

  <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then trying to inflate this layout in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method of a RecyclerView adapter like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public CustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_layout, parent, false);
    return new CustomHolder(itemView, (AppCompatActivity) inflater.getContext());
}
```

I then put different Fragments, depending on if the user has clicked a list item or not, into the list item in the CustomHolder:

```
class CustomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public static boolean skip = true;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    private FragmentContainerView fragmentContainerView;
    private Fragment attributeDetailFragment;
    private Trainer trainer;
    private TextView trainerAge;

    CustomHolder(@NonNull View itemView, AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        super(itemView);
        this.trainerAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trainer_age);
        this.fragmentContainerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
    }

    void setTrainer(Trainer trainer) {
        this.trainer = trainer;
        this.trainerAge.setText(" " + trainer.getAge());
        this.trainerAge.setOnClickListener(this::onTrainerAgeClick);
        itemView.setTag(this);
    }

    private void onTrainerAgeClick(View view) {
        attributeDetailFragment = new AgeFragment();
        showFragment();
    }

    private void showFragment() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("trainer", trainer);
        attributeDetailFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentContainerView.getId(), attributeDetailFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

However upon running the app, when clicking on different listitems, the correct content will be set into a fragment, but the Fragment will always land in the FragmentContainerView of the first listitem. This is what the previous version of this question meant by the id stays the same, the FragmentContainerView targeted stays the same but the TextView targeted changes depending on the ViewHolder object.

From the comments on this, I suspect it may be the `fragmentContainerView.getId()` in `showFragment()`, but I have no idea with what I should replace it, since `replace()` needs an int id.

Comment: You're somehow trying to use this the wrong way. A RecyclerView inflates the same layout every time because it sets up the content in `onBindViewHolder`, maybe even a fragment and you deliberately don't distinguish between the views because they get recycled and reconfigured during scrolling. Also ". This is different from what happens when inflating TextViews, or any other views, which will have unique ids even when inflated multiple times" no? That would be news to me, an id in xml is fixed once the app is compiled

Comment: Zapl is right, TextViews will behave the same, in trying to provide as little code and as much generalization as possible I've accidentally betrayed my noobiness and generalized too much. I will edit the post to be more specific to the problem I'm having.

Comment: Adding fragment in a `RecyclerView` isn't going to work (the "recycling" part of `RecyclerView` won't play nicely with Fragments). You'll need to come up with a different design.